# Why is the learning rate is already very small (1e-05) while the model convergences too fast?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am training a video prediction model.

According to the loss plots, the model convergences very fast while the final loss is not small enough and the generation is not good.

Actually, I have test the `lr=1e-04`and `lr=1e-05`, the loss plots drop down a little more slowly, but it's still not ideal. But I think `lr=1e-05`should be small enough, isn't it?

How should I fix my model or the hyper parameters?